# What if all virus suddenly disappear?

Tags: virology, life

Exactly as the question says:

Let's say that **all** the viruses suddenly disappear (it doesn't matter the cause, just evaporate!): what would happened with the life on Earth?

I know: if this question says "bacteria", that would be a cataclysm, but with virus?

Note: let me know if this is not a correct space for this question. Thanks!

Comment: As a new user to SE Biology it would be courteous to our community if you read to the end of the [Tour] where you would see that questions that are primarily opinion-based are not suitable for this site. This is expanded in the [Help on questions to avoid asking](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask_), which specifically refers to the case: "you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?".

Comment: I think it's a very interesting question because viruses have a major impact on many fields of global populations, climate and chemistry.

Comment: Viruses are the fungus of the bacterial world, they also naturally control invasive invertebrate, plant and pest populations, and have an effect on geochemistry and climate. https://www.google.com/search?q=main+effects+of+viruses+on+planet+earth&oq=main+effects+of+viruses+on+planet+earth&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160.6752j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: ha - i'd say. more like its a viral world and the bacteria and fungi just live in it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm okay with speculative questions — they are often re-writeable into typical SE questions.

My short answer is that we guess but we don't really know.  Viruses do keep many bacterial and microbial populations in check.  They cause disease too but I'm guessing that they also transport information from one point in the ecosystem.  I remember some of the research into cholera showed that [disease causing genes in *Vibrio cholerae* are transmitted by phage](https://www.science.org/doi/abs/10.1126/science.272.5270.1910) (a bacterial virus).  So that suggests that benign bacteria have reserves of phenotypes which they can pull out of the virosphere when they need to change their stripes.

How often does this sort of thing happen? We know so little about the estimated millions of bacterial species, much less how they might effect the microbial ecosystem.

I feel *something* would happen but it's really hard to say what.  Would viruses come back? there are quite a few viruses embedded in genomes, which reactivate at interval.  It's easier to imagine the earth scrubbed of all life before viruses would be gone!  Just sayin'

Answer (score 1):

Their disappearance will not be much impactful because these are damaging to cells only, but we can also see this situation from another angle.
Many viruses act as 'bacteria eaters' such as bacteriophages. Most of these viruses are the main factors in slowing down the exponential reproduction rate of bacteria.
A typical bacteria duplicates every 25 minutes. On the other hand, the viral reproduction rate is extremely high. For instance, during the "lytic cycle", T-4 bacteriophage even reduces the number of bacteria in a bacterial population.
Moreover, the disappearance of all viruses will be dramatically beneficial for humans, as viruses are the main causative agents of many of dangerous diseases.Mian examples include influenza, small pox, AIDS, hepatitis, measles and mumps.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. This is an objective question and answer site, not a discussion site, so it would be better to ignore this sort of "What if?" sort of question. See my comment on the actual question for a more detailed explanation of this.